# Data is not getting stored in a database through a customer form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I made a customer feedback form with rating stars. But problem is, not getting stored data in database. Where the actual problem occured? What is the relevent solution? I tried many time.

***forms.py:***

```
class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
    feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)     
    rating = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
```

***models.py:***

```
class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
feedBACK = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***views.py:***

```
def quick_view(request, quick_view_id):
    form = FeedBackForm()
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = FeedBackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ProductREVIEWS.objects.create(
                feedBACK=form.cleaned_data.get('feedBACK'),
                rating=form.cleaned_data.get('product_rating'),
            )
```

***template:***

```
<form action="#!" method="POST" class="needs-validation mt-3" style="font-size: 13px;" novalidate="" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="radio-toolbar d-flex">
        <input type="radio" id="one_star" name="product_rating" value="1" checked>
        <label for="one_star" class="mx-1">1 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="two_star" name="product_rating" value="2">
        <label for="two_star" class="mx-1">2 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="three_star" name="product_rating" value="3">
        <label for="three_star" class="mx-1">3 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="four_star" name="product_rating" value="4">
        <label for="four_star" class="mx-1">4 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="five_star" name="product_rating" value="5">
        <label for="five_star" class="mx-1">5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3 mt-2">
        <textarea id="email" placeholder="Share your experiencs..." rows="10" style="font-size: 13px; text-transform: lowercase;" type="email" class="form-control" name="feedBACK" value="" required></textarea>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you are not doing anything with `FeedBackForm`, so you can simply get the names of fields through POST request in view as:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def quick_view(request, quick_view_id):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        ProductREVIEWS.objects.create(
            feedBACK=request.POST.get('feedBACK'),
            rating=request.POST.get('product_rating')
        )
        return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'some_folder_name/index.html')


def success(request):
    return render(request, 'some_folder_name/success.html')
```

> `Note:` Its a good practice to redirect after dealing with POST data.

Template file:

```html
<form method="POST" class="needs-validation mt-3" style="font-size: 13px;"   autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="radio-toolbar d-flex">
        <input type="radio" id="one_star" name="product_rating" value="1" checked>
        <label for="one_star" class="mx-1">1 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="two_star" name="product_rating" value="2">
        <label for="two_star" class="mx-1">2 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="three_star" name="product_rating" value="3">
        <label for="three_star" class="mx-1">3 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="four_star" name="product_rating" value="4">
        <label for="four_star" class="mx-1">4 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

        <input type="radio" id="five_star" name="product_rating" value="5">
        <label for="five_star" class="mx-1">5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3 mt-2">
        <textarea id="email" placeholder="Share your experiencs..." rows="10" style="font-size: 13px; text-transform: lowercase;" type="email" class="form-control" name="feedBACK" value="" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('success/',views.success,name='success')
]
```

success.html

```html
<body>
    <h2>Form successfully submitted.</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Now it shown this error::::::'FeedBackForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: @Mossaddak check again you must use `request.POST.get()` not `form.cleaned_data.get()`.

Comment: worked,thank you. But I wanted to do it with a form

Comment: @Mossaddak so you should use modelform.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't actually utilising the functionality of Django forms. Firstly, I would suggest using a model form rather than just a normal form - it will automatically do some of the lifting to connect the form with your model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Secondly, you are validating the form using `is_valid()` but you are then manually creating the object - you can instead using `save()` to create the model.