# Form data not stored in database. What is the problem?

Tags: django

***This form working working perfectly,***

```
class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
        feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

***But this form didn't work***

```
class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
    feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)     
    rating = forms.CharField(widget=forms.IntegerField, required=True)
```

***It is showing below error.***  Where did the problem occur? I checked documentation but no clue I found.

```
AttributeError at /quick_view/11/
'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/quick_view/11/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py, line 224, in _widget_data_value
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site\\env',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce '
 'site\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 13 Jul 2022 10:41:38 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

An [**`IntegerField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) is a form *field*, not a *widget*. You specify the field as:

```
class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
    feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)     
    rating = forms.IntegerField()
```

---

> **Note**: By default, a form field has [**`required=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required), hence you do not need to mark fields as required.

Comment: But problem is I can't store data through form, class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
    feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)     
    rating = forms.IntegerField() ,,through form I can't strore data,,,,,, but it's worked::class FeedBackForm(forms.Form):
    feedBACK = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)   ........please check this question:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956570/data-is-not-getting-stored-in-a-database-through-a-customer-form/72957428#72957428  ]

Comment: @Mossaddak: likely because the first one is a `ModelForm` whereas the latter is a simple form.

Comment: Now what I've to do?